# Looking for a regex to chunk a string into 2,3,4... words

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have this string:

```
This is a test sentence. Actually, it is a paragraph really. Lets see how this goes
```

And I want to chunk it on individual words (including punctuation). For example, 2 words at a time:

```
This is 
a test 
sentence. Actually, 
it is 
a paragraph 
really. Lets 
see how 
this goes
```

I can get individual words using:

```
/\w*(\D)\s*/g
```

Thats great, but when I try 3 words using something like this:

```
/(\w*\D)\s(\w*\D)\s(\w*\D)/g
```

It doesn't feel right, and doesn't look very elegant. Some words are left "dangling" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. Instead of "3" have the number-1 of words per line you want as demonstrated in the example (3 gives 4 words).

```
var s = 'This is a test sentence. Actually, it is a paragraph really. Lets see how this goes'
undefined
s.match(/(\S+)(\s+\S+){0,3}/g)
Array [ "This is a test", "sentence. Actually, it is", "a paragraph really. Lets", "see how this goes" ]
```

Comment: This is great, s.match(/(\S+)(\s+\S+){0,2}/g) even includes a word from the end

Answer (score 2):

Use `\S+` to match one or more non-space characters.

```
> var s = 'This is a test sentence. Actually, it is a paragraph really. Lets see how this goes'
undefined
> s.match(/\S+\s+\S+/g)
[ 'This is',
  'a test',
  'sentence. Actually,',
  'it is',
  'a paragraph',
  'really. Lets',
  'see how',
  'this goes' ]
```

Comment: Same var name and same regex, but you are too quick :) +1

Comment: for three words `s.match(/\S+(?:\s+\S+){2}/g)`

Comment: This is great, however when using /\S+(?:\s+\S+){2}/g there is a word missing from the end :(

Comment: but you didn't talk about the missing words.. how about this `s.match(/\S+(?:(?:\s+\S+){2})?/g)` ?